# getting comments and its replies

Tags: sql

I have a table called `comments,` with the columns: `id`, `title`, `comment`, `reply_to,create_date`.  Its a PostgreSQL DB, version 8.3.
The column `reply_to` references the comment that is being is replied to.
I want to get comments with all their replies.

```
Id / title / comment / reply_to / create_date  / reply_id / reply_title / reply_comment / reply_reply_to  / reply_create_date

7 / hello  / this is john / 6 / 2011-1-2   / 8  / Re:hello / Hello John! / 7 / 2011-1-4

7 / hello  / this is john / 6 / 2011-1-2   / 9  / Re:hello / John, welcome! / 7 / 2011-1-2

7 / hello  / this is john / 6 / 2011-1-2   / 10  / Re:hello / Nice to meet you, John / 7 / 2011-1-1
```

The comment with id 7 has been replied to by the comments with id 8, 9 and 10.
To get that, I used this query:

```
Select comments.id,comments.title
      ,comments.comment
      ,comments.reply_to
      ,comments.create_date
      ,B.id as reply_id
      ,B.title as reply_title
      ,B.comment as reply_comment
      ,B.reply to as reply_reply_to
      ,B. create_date as reply_create_date
  from comments 
  left join (select * from comments) B ON comments.id=B.reply_to
 order by create_date, reply_create_date DESC
```

That works fine, but now I would like to get only the last two replies for every comment, so the result should be:

```
7 / hello  / this is john / 6 / 2011-1-2   / 8  / Re:hello / Hello John! / 7 / 2011-1-4

7 / hello  / this is john / 6 / 2011-1-2   / 9  / Re:hello / John, welcome! / 7 / 2011-1-2
```

I thought using `limit` and `offset` in the query would help, but if I put them at the last part of the query, it only takes 2 of all the comments. If I put them inside the B query, only takes 2 of all the replies.

Comment: Something's not quite right with your sample data... http://sqlize.com/t6MkBoA610

Comment: Please remember to always tell what RDBMS (database) and version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

In **PostgreSQL 9.0** your query could look like this:

```
SELECT c.id
      ,c.title
      ,c.comment
      ,c.reply_to
      ,c.create_date
      ,b.reply_id
      ,b.reply_title
      ,b.reply_comment
      ,b.reply_reply_to
      ,b.reply_create_date
  FROM comments c
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT b.id          AS reply_id
          ,b.title       AS reply_title
          ,b.comment     AS reply_comment
          ,b.reply_to    AS reply_reply_to
          ,b.create_date AS reply_create_date
          ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY b.reply_to ORDER BY b.create_date DESC) AS rn
      FROM comments b
     WHERE rn < 3) b ON b.reply_to = c.id
 ORDER BY c.create_date, c.id, b.reply_create_date DESC;
```

#### Major points

- use [window function row_number()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) to get the latest 2 postings
- retrieves the columns you listed (for unknown reasons) plus a maximum of two replies
- Includes comments with no replies at all (reply-fields are NULL then)

Comment: I tried  to use "over" , but it throws an error. Im using postgreSQL 8.3.15, so i guess i will have to look for another way. Thanks a lot, it was a great solution, though.

Comment: @Kane This is because you did not tell which RDBMS you are using (i.e. which brand and version).